# Datagridview header location

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to move my header locations from the top(columns) and the left(rows) to the right(rows) and bottom(columns). I can only find information for aliments for the content within the headers, not the alignment of the headers themselves.

see photo below for example of this...

[image]

I know it might be tricky to then add items accordingly to the datagridview, but my data needs to be organized this way as opposed to headers on the top and left. (if using a datagridview is too hard, is there another object i can use?)

As always, THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, this is not possible in Winforms. I don't know how it is in WPF and I don't know any other out-of-the-box solutions.

My proposal:
You could cheat by adding a DGV on the right and one on the bottom. They only contain the headers. Then you need to 'connect' the scrolling events of the DGVs.
You got an idea what I'm meaning?

Not the nicest solution and for sure a bit tricky, but probably the only one.

Comment: A good idea for a work around... if there truly is no other way I might just go ahead an do this :)

Answer (score 1):

The RightToLeft property of the DataGridView solves the headers left alignment.

For the bottom alignment, I am afraid that there is no simple solution.

Comment: Yes, changing the RightToLeft property did change the row alignment quite nicely. I believe doing this, then possibly adding a second DGV directly below this one will be the best solution!

Comment: Creating a DGV2 is probably the best. But, you may need to forward variation of column width from one DGV to the other one and  process DGV1 sort when clicking on DGV2 headers.

Comment: I think the only negative about using the RightToLeft property is that now the entire table gets shifted to the right-most side of the DGV